# df.columns is giving ValueError: in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am completely new in pyspark. I am getting error while executing the command

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("basics").getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.csv("data.csv",inferSchema=True,header=True)  
df.columns
```

my data has 1,000,000 rows and 50 columns. I am getting following error.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-b666bf274d0a> in <module>
----> 1 df.columns

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in columns(self)
    935         ['age', 'name']
    936         """
--> 937         return [f.name for f in self.schema.fields]
    938 
    939     @since(2.3)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in schema(self)
    253         if self._schema is None:
    254             try:
--> 255                 self._schema = _parse_datatype_json_string(self._jdf.schema().json())
    256             except AttributeError as e:
    257                 raise Exception(

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/types.py in _parse_datatype_json_string(json_string)
    867     >>> check_datatype(complex_maptype)
    868     """
--> 869     return _parse_datatype_json_value(json.loads(json_string))
    870 
    871 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/types.py in _parse_datatype_json_value(json_value)
    884         tpe = json_value["type"]
    885         if tpe in _all_complex_types:
--> 886             return _all_complex_types[tpe].fromJson(json_value)
    887         elif tpe == 'udt':
    888             return UserDefinedType.fromJson(json_value)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/types.py in fromJson(cls, json)
    575     @classmethod
    576     def fromJson(cls, json):
--> 577         return StructType([StructField.fromJson(f) for f in json["fields"]])
    578 
    579     def fieldNames(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/types.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    575     @classmethod
    576     def fromJson(cls, json):
--> 577         return StructType([StructField.fromJson(f) for f in json["fields"]])
    578 
    579     def fieldNames(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/types.py in fromJson(cls, json)
    432     def fromJson(cls, json):
    433         return StructField(json["name"],
--> 434                            _parse_datatype_json_value(json["type"]),
    435                            json["nullable"],
    436                            json["metadata"])

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/types.py in _parse_datatype_json_value(json_value)
    880             return DecimalType(int(m.group(1)), int(m.group(2)))
    881         else:
--> 882             raise ValueError("Could not parse datatype: %s" % json_value)
    883     else:
    884         tpe = json_value["type"]

ValueError: Could not parse datatype: decimal(6,-8)
```

Can anyone please help me to understand why am I getting this error and how to over come this? If I am getting the error because of wrong schema, how can I define the schema for 50 columns? TIA!

Comment: can you provide the code you're writing and how your'e creating the df.
I suspect your schema is not correct, can only confirm if I see the code.

Comment: @EladCohen I have modified the my question and added the code to import data. I can understand that the error is due to wrong schema, but how can I write schema when I am many columns?

Comment: you can try turn `inferSchema` off y removing it, the `inferSchema` iterate through the data one more time and try to determined the schema automatically, try without it.

Comment: Thanks @EladCohen turning off the interSchema is working properly but it is converting all the columns into string.

Comment: I added a code that should help you fix the auto schema casting.

Answer (score 0):

according to what you commented, use `inferSchema=True` and this UNTESTED code should help you out:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("basics").getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.csv("data.csv",inferSchema=True,header=True)  
for column_type in df.dtypes:
    if 'string' in column_type[1]:
        df = df.withColumn(column_type[0], df[column_type[0]].cast(StringType()))
    elif 'double' in column_type[1]:
        df = df.withColumn(column_type[0],df[column_type[0]].cast(DoubleType()))
    elif 'int' in column_type[1]:
        df = df.withColumn(column_type[0],df[column_type[0]].cast(IntegerType()))
    elif 'bool' in column_type[1]:
        df = df.withColumn(column_type[0], df[column_type[0]].cast(BooleanType()))
    elif 'decimal' in column_type[1]:
        df = df.withColumn(column_type[0],df[column_type[0]].cast(DoubleType()))
    # add as many condiitions as you need for types

df.schema
```

let me know if it did it for you, if not than i'll test and update it

Comment: Thanks @Elad, but I am getting the following error: I guess a closing bracket is missing.  the error is: File "<ipython-input-21-4903ff843083>", line 6
    df = df.withColumn(column_type[0], df[column_type[0].cast(StringType()))
                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: you are right I forgot the closing `]` bracket after `column_type[0]`, i fixed it

Comment: Thanks. I have already tried the code with closing ]. but still getting the same error.

Comment: could you upload a sample of the data you have been using? I'll run it myself and see.

Comment: Sorry I can't do this due to confidentiality issues.

Comment: Alright, you can try the code with `inferSchema=False` and see what happens.
I suspect theres a problem with the data that causes spark to not recognize the dtype well.

Comment: Also, the type from your error is decimal, have you tried to add more conditions to the code? such as `elif 'decimal' in column_type[1]: ...`? I edited the code as such, give it a try, the problem as I said, is in your data, the dtype is decimal but your data isn't.